# How to use shell script to read a log file line by line and extract timestamp and file size information?

Tags: bash, shell

I want to extract the timestamp and file size information from a log file line by line, each line is in the following format:

34600 - - [30/Apr/1998:21:30:17 +0000] "GET /images/hm_bg.jpg HTTP/1.0" 200 24736

The bracket contains timestamp and the last segment '24736' stands for file size.

Can anyone know how to do it using shell script or other language?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like

```
#!/bin/bash
while read -r line; do
  [[ $line =~ '['(.*)']' ]] && echo "${BASH_REMATCH[1]} ${line##*' '}"
done < file
```

e.g.

```
> cat file
34600 - - [30/Apr/1998:21:30:17 +0000] "GET /images/hm_bg.jpg HTTP/1.0" 200 24736

> while read -r line; do [[ $line =~ '['(.*)']' ]] && echo "DATE=${BASH_REMATCH[1]} SIZE=${line##*' '}"; done < file
DATE=30/Apr/1998:21:30:17 +0000 SIZE=24736
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `awk`:

```
awk '{sub(/[][]/,""); printf "DATE: %s SIZE: %s \n", $4,$NF}' file
Date: 30/Apr/1998:21:30:17 Size: 24736
```

Answer (score 0):

Using sed

```
sed -nr 's/.*\[([^]]*)\].* ([0-9]+)/\1 \2/p' file

30/Apr/1998:21:30:17 +0000 24736
```